# Enable WPF button based on checkbox list selection in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a checkbox list items and a submit button. The submit button initially need to be disabled. The button needs to be enabled by selection of single checkbox selection or multiple selections. I add below code in XAML and backend code need to have a view model suing MVVM.

XAML..

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="10 5 20 0" SelectionMode="Extended">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Name="check" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5 5 0 10" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value}" Margin="5 5 0 10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

<Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="25" Width="60" Margin="0,0,30,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsButtonEnabled}">                    <TextBlock>Submit</TextBlock> </Button>
```

So how would be the view model implement using OnPropertyChanged().

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to do it, but why not use binding/multibinding and a converter?

Comment: So can you just add an answer for that using converter?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to register to all the `PropertyChanged` events of each item in the view model and aggregate the results. For example:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedHandler = (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Item.IsChecked))
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnabled));
        };

        Items.CollectionChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.OldItems != null)
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
                    item.PropertyChanged -= propertyChangedHandler;
            if (e.NewItems != null)
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
                    item.PropertyChanged += propertyChangedHandler;
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }

    public bool IsButtonEnabled => Items.Any(i => i.IsChecked);
}
```

Another option to consider is using [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/).

Comment: How whould be the xaml of the button should be?

Comment: Need to bind sample items in to listbox "Items" object. and this code is not working if i need to do some more than this?